# Android: connect bluetooth after intent ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

I have this code that if the bluetooth is not turned on, it will pop up the intent and request to enable it, but if the bluetooth is turned on already it will automatically connect to the "HC-O5" bluetooth module.

Now I want it also to automatically connect after enabling the bluetooth through the intent. What would I have to add to my code? this what I have:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.log_in);
    setupViews();
    buttonListeners();

    handler = new Handler();

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);

        }
        else {
            pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                    //myDevices.append("\n  Device: " + device.getName() + ", " + device);
                    if(device.getName().equals("HC-05")) {
                        mmDevice = device;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    openBT();
                    beginListenForData();
                } catch (IOException ex) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. So I deleted the answer. Please describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: `if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);

        }` 

at the start of the app this code will display the dialog box to enable bluetooth if the bluetooth is not turned on, is there a way i can automatically connect it to the bluetooth module after enabling it?